# How to echo makefile variable through Make's $(shell ...)

Tags: shell, make, echo, mingw

I have a [GNU makefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile). The makefile has a few tests (around line 65 from the linked file):

```
UNAME = uname

MACHINE ?= $(shell $(UNAME) -m)
SYSTEM ?= $(shell $(UNAME) -s)

IS_X86 = $(shell echo $MACHINE | $(EGREP) -c "i.86|x86|i86|amd64")
IS_X86_64 = $(shell echo $MACHINE | $(EGREP) -c "_64|d64")
```

The makefile is failing to set `IS_X86` and `IS_X86_64` properly under MinGW and its `sh` shell. When I add the following after the block of tests:

```
$(info MACHINE: $(MACHINE))
$(info SYSTEM: $(SYSTEM))
$(info IS_X86: $(IS_X86))
$(info IS_X86_64: $(IS_X86_64))
```

And I get in return:

```
$ make
MACHINE: i686
SYSTEM: MINGW32_NT-6.1
IS_X86: 0
IS_X86_64: 0
```

I'm presuming MinGW can match `i686` to `i.86`, so I'm guessing there's something wrong with the `echo` command or the variable under MinGW.

I also tried the following with no joy:

```
$(shell echo $(MACHINE) ...)
$(shell echo $((MACHINE)) ...)
```

I even tried to force the variable expansion before the tests:

```
MACHINE := $(MACHINE)
```

Finally, I tried using a temporary with no joy:

```
MTEXT ?= $(shell $(UNAME) -m)
MACHINE := $(MTEXT)
```

The tests work fine under the BSDs, Linux, OS X and Solaris. It even works under Cygwin.

What is the trick to using `echo` under MinGW to echo a makefile variable?

Comment: Perhaps, your make does not use the `bash` but another unexpected `sh` binary in your mingw environment ...

Comment: @maxschlepzig - you are right - its `/bin/sh`. Let me get it tagged properly...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a weird shell in your mingw environment - and not bash. Or a weird version of egrep.

You can work around this via replacing those egrep shell calls with GNU make conditionals, e.g.:

```
ifeq (,$(filter %686 %x86 %i86 %amd64,$(MACHINE)))
  IS_X86 = 0
else
  IS_X86 = 1
endif
```

Alternatively, you could create something based on [`$(findstring ...)` or other GNU make text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html).

Besides working around your current problem, using such GNU make language feature is also more efficient than forking left and right via `$(shell)`.

Comment: Thanks maxschlepzig. I'm not sure what shell it is. I'll try your recommendations. I keep Cygwin and MinGW around for testing only. We are getting ready to release Crypto++ 5.6.3, so I'm in a testing cycle.